# Non-homogeneous equations system solution number

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If in non-homogeneous system of equations$\ AX = B$ , every equation's value is smaller than variable $\ X$, then:

```
- A)  AX = B has unlimited number of solutions;
- B)  AX = B has only one solution;
- C)  AX = 0 has unlimited number of solutions;
- D)  AX = 0 the only solution for this equation is 0;
```

C is a correct answer but I don't really understand why. I can understand that D is 100% incorrect since A can be 0, X will be a set (0;+$\infty$).

However first two answers are puzzling me and I can't quite get it.

Comment: What is the `value` of an equation? An how can it be smaller than a variable?

Comment: Yeah my bad, I meant A and B. Basically, if A and B are smaller than X then what will be the solution set for this equation.

Comment: How do you compare  matrices?